# Sending body in 415 error when client Accept-Encoding prohibits `identity`

Tags: http, encoding, http-headers

I’m encountering a scenario where a client sends a request with the `Accept-Encoding` header explicitly prohibiting "identity" (no encoding). In the event that the server is unable to fulfil the acceptable encodings specified by the client, how should the server handle encoding the body of the 415 Unsupported Media Type error?

Consider the following client requests:

```http
Accept-Encoding: br, identity;q=0
# or
Accept-Encoding: br, *;q=0
```

In these examples, the client explicitly requests Brotli and prohibits any other encoding, including "identity."

Now, if the server is only capable of responding with either `gzip` or `identity`, neither of which the client is willing to accept, what is the appropriate approach for the server to include a body in the 415 response?

[RFC 9110: HTTP Semantics, 12.5.3. Accept-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-accept-encoding) states:

> If the representation has no content coding, then it is acceptable by default unless specifically excluded by the Accept-Encoding header field stating either "identity;q=0" or "*;q=0" without a more specific entry for "identity".

> Servers that fail a request due to an unsupported content coding ought to respond with a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status and include an Accept-Encoding header field in that response…